# Spacing between 3 columns DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here an example that I want

[image]

Those images are loaded from a while loop in MySQL and would like that the spacing between them make in sort that the left column and right are touching each side and the middle in centered. Like the picture :D

The CSS I have:

```
#realisation .box{
    float:left;
    width:286px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
}

#realisation .box:last-child{
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

And the loop

```
<div class="box">
    <div><img src="imgs/beta/imgpasrap.jpg" width="286" height="176"/></div>
    <p>Text here</p>
  </div>
```

It's working great for the first 3 box, but more than that, the display is messed up. How could I achieve that like the picture above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a width on the box containing all of these images. (reference: http://jsfiddle.net/52TUV/)
(note:  the styles for the images are only to maintain their size - they do not need to be added)

```html
<div id="outer">
    <!-- image HTML stuff goes here -->
</div>
```

```css
#outer{
    width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Yup did the trick thanks! Didn't know such a simple look could be hard to think off ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="className">
    <!-- image -->
</div>

.className{
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/css-columns-using-lists/

The :last-child() selector is not supported in any of the major browsers.

Comment: No keep in mind that I have multiple rows too, not only 3 columns in 1 row. The 4th div that I will make will break the float.

Comment: The :last-child selector is most definitely supported in major browsers. It is just older browsers where the support becomes patchy.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.product_image{
    float:left;
    background:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #ccc;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++){ ?>
<div class="product_image"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>
<?php 
if($i%3==0){
echo '<div class=clear></div>';
}
} ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Relace For Loop with your while loop than show which you want. Use only thumbnail image bye